# Using same classes for items and lists

Tags: vb.net, class, objectdatasource

Reviewing code for a .net website project, most of the classes have been created with extensive properties. These have then been used as datasources for listviews and repeaters which do not use all the properties retrieved from SQL.

For example, binding a List(Of Contact) to a repeater however the repeater only needs id, nickname, fullname, postcode

Detailed class for item:

```
Public Class Contact
Private _id as integer = 0
Private _nickname As String = ""
Private _email As String = ""
Private _website As String = ""
Private _titleID As Integer = 1
Private _fullname As String = ""
Private _address1 as string = ""
```

and 20 more variables.

Edit: Followed by 27 properties, constructor and shared methods to complete the class (ref plutonix)

Can you selectively retrieve some of the properties from SQL when binding to an object. Or, do you need separate classes for lists which use fewer properties? Linq is not used.

Comment: This is very broad and almost asks for a tutorial.  But a) none of those things are Properties and b) none of them will be visiable outside the class since they are private.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can set only properties that you want, but keep in mind, that rest of the properties will have their type's default values.

Comment: thanks - so if the SQL field 'website' is nvarchar(75) but defaults to zero length string in the class, does this mean that the list will have a zero length property for 'website'

Comment: It means that list will have String property will default value of String - Nothing (null in C#). But if you will have some property with for example DateTime, it will have default value of DateTime.MinValue (1.1.0001) which takes some space in memory and that must be considered when high amount of items are used (100 000+)

Comment: Also it is important how data is mapped from DB to .NET class, aka which O/R mapper you using.

Comment: That is very very old technique for getting data from database. I recommend you to learn about O/R mappers.